# Add a linked message at the top of cart page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, notice

I'd like to add a link to my email subscription form at the top of my Cart page. I have the following cart related templates:

- `cart-empty.php`
- `cart-item-data.php`
- `cart-shipping.php`
- `cart-totals.php`
- `cart.php`

If what I want is possible, do I add the necessary code in one of those, or in my functions.php?

Let me know if you want me to copy the code of any of those templates for the purposes of answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will display a custom message with a linked text button in the top of cart page:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'add_cart_custom_notice');
function add_cart_custom_notice() {
    // HERE the link to your content
    $link = '#';

    // For example, print a notice with a linked button (the text is editable and translatable)
    wc_print_notice( sprintf( '<span class="subscription-reminder">' .
        __('Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames  %s', 'woocommerce') . '</span>',
        '<a href='.$link.' class="button alt" style="float:right">'. __('Go to the subscription form', 'woocommerce') .'</a>'
    ), 'notice' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: You are the man, as always! Thank you! Could I assign a class to that text as well?

Comment: @JohnHolliday Yes you can, I have updated the code adding a `<span>` html tag with a class… try it.

Comment: worked just like you said. Thank you again. Out of curiosity - is this answer specific to a particular version of php?

Comment: @JohnHolliday No it should handle for sure any version from PHP 5.4

Answer (score 0):

You can add notice on cart page using WooCommerce wc_add_notice function.

Or to move cart templates in child theme 'woocommerce' folder and customize.